# How do i write this query

Tags: mysql

Here is the problem

Using the CASE expression, display the author’s first name concatenated to his last name separated by a space concatenated to a “  is:  “. Concatenate the previous result to a slogan based on the value in the state column. If state is “CA” display “Sunny”. If state is “CO”, display “a rarity”. If state is “FL”, display “a peach”. If state is “NY”, display “likes apple pie”. Name the column “Author Characteristics”. Order the result by “Author Characteristics”.

Here is the code I have written so far

```
select concat(au_fname, au_lname, ' is: '),
case state
    when 'CA'
        then 'Sunny'
    when 'CO'
        then 'a rarity'
    when 'FL'
        then 'a peach'
    when 'NY'
        then 'like apple pie'
    else 'state'
end
AS "Author Characteristics"
FROM authors
ORDER BY 1;
```

The problem i am having is the output is giving me two columns, one titled from the concat statement and the second column is titled Author Characteristics.  I need to get just one field so the information is all together with only one title.

Comment: Georgia is the peach state.  Florida is the sunshine state.  However, we do have better peaches

Comment: Why don't you select an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just make the `case` another argument to `CONCAT`.

```
select concat(au_first, au_last, ' is: ', case state
when 'CA' then 'Sunny' when 'CO' then 'a rarity' when 'FL' then 'a peach'
when 'NY' then 'like apple pie' else 'state' end) AS "Author Characteristics"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
select concat(au_fname, au_lname, ' is: ',
case state
    when 'CA'
        then 'Sunny'
    when 'CO'
        then 'a rarity'
    when 'FL'
        then 'a peach'
    when 'NY'
        then 'like apple pie'
    else 'state'
end )
AS "Author Characteristics"
FROM authors
ORDER BY 1;
```

This will include the 'state' values in your `concat` statement. In your original code, you ended up with two columns because the `concat` statement resulted in one column, and the `case` in another.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have one column in the result list, you also need to include the `CASE` statement inside the `CONCAT()` function. But in `ORDER BY` clause, you need again to have the `CASE` statement since you want to order them by state. Orderinf the records by `ORDER BY 1` will sort the records on `au_fname`.

```
select  concat(au_fname, ' ',au_lname, ' is: ', 
                case state
                    when 'CA' then 'Sunny'
                    when 'CO' then 'a rarity'
                    when 'FL' then 'a peach'
                    when 'NY' then 'like apple pie'
                    else 'state'
                end) `Author Characteristics`
FROM authors
ORDER BY case state
            when 'CA' then 'Sunny'
            when 'CO' then 'a rarity'
            when 'FL' then 'a peach'
            when 'NY' then 'like apple pie'
            else 'state' end
```

but if I misunderstood the question, you can directly order them via the `ALIAS`,

```
ORDER BY `Author Characteristics`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*provided by acdcjunior*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6177/10)

Comment: I was gonna answer exactly like you, but you beat me to it. Anyway, here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c6177/10 , hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Include the 'case' statement within the 'concat' function

```
select concat(au_fname, au_lname, ' is: ', 
case state
when 'CA'
    then 'Sunny'
when 'CO'
    then 'a rarity'
when 'FL'
    then 'a peach'
when 'NY'
    then 'like apple pie'
else 'state'
end)
AS "Author Characteristics"
FROM authors
ORDER BY 1;
```